# Maximo Crew Type Quantity from JOBLABOR to WPLABOR

Tags: maximo

if CrewType is chosen on JobPlan, Maximo's default behaviour is to explicitly set Quantity to 1 and make it read-only. I have changed that behaviour in JOBLABOR, and now I can edit the Quantity on JobPlan. (This has been done via an attribute launch point automation script on JOBLABOR.AMCREWTYPE).

However, when the JobPlan is applied to a WO, it still explicitly sets the QUANTITY for CrewType as 1 on WPLABOR, thus not carrying across the quantity from JOBLABOR. Where can i override that behaviour?  Could this be done via an automation script for the run action of JPNUM field?

Comment: Please consider reading the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on How to Ask a Good Question.

Comment: Is this not just a default value set on the field in Database Configuration? When you say you "changed that behaviour in JOBLABOR", how did you do that? If you can provide a little more information on what you're trying to achieve it's likely someone can help and perhaps this can be done without customisation.

Comment: i have updated as requested. thank!

Comment: "Could this be done via an automation script for the run action of JPNUM field?" Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you would want to plan for *n* crews of some type. For example, it takes a crew of a certain type to stand a pole for street lights, and if you've got a whole street to put lights on, why not have 5 of that crew type planned on this work order?

Unfortunately, it seems Maximo is pretty set against doing that. For what explanation it may yield, I recommend opening a Support Case with IBM, asking for the rationale or how to work around that limitation. And you could [submit an RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRFEs) with rationale for why the limitation should not be there.

To satisfy the immediate need,  maybe you could set up crew types as a service? Or create your own Quantity attributes for use with Crew Type and implement all the logic around those? I don't like reinventing the wheel, but "the juice might be worth the squeeze" if you're going to be fighting Maximo every step of the way, anyway. Or, if it really means that much to you, customize this aspect of Maximo to do what you want.

Whatever happens, I think your problem is not a programming problem but a Maximo problem. And as StackOverflow is a programming site, your problem is beyond the scope of this site. However, please come back if you have a programming problem! We love solving those!

**Update**

Having thought more about this, I think this is not a Maximo problem. I think Maximo is just (you could argue, forcibly) encouraging better planning. In the street light example, you wouldn't expect *n* crews to self-organize to stand poles. That would be poor planning. Rather, you would have a top level work order for doing the street with a lower level work order for each individual pole. So, each of those lower level work orders would only require 1 of the Crew Type. This arrangement would still flow through to scheduling as needing *n* of that Crew Type, but whether 1 Crew of that type was used *n* times or whether *n* crews were used once or somewhere in between is a scheduling problem, not a planning problem.

Comment: Thank you Preacher :)

It is indeed a Maximo problem!

Comment: thanks for the update; I am speaking with the schedulers at this client to understand how best  this could be resolved without  customizations.

Answer (score 0):

As to why the quantity field defaults back to 1 and is made read-only if Crew Type or Crew are selected, I would expect that's because conceptually, it doesn't make sense to have a quantity other than one for these types of job plan labour.  The same is true of assigning labour records to a Job Plan because it doesn't make sense to assign a quantity greater than one of the same person's labour record.  In fact the only type of job plan labour you're able to adjust the quantity for in Maximo out of the box is craft because you could justifiably require multiples of a particular craft (e.g. 3 electricians) assigned to the job plan.

A crew type is a template for a crew which is itself the labour (internal or otherwise) with particular crafts, skill levels and qualifications to perform the work.  Since each Crew is distinct and made up of group of individuals assigned to the positions in the crew I don't think it makes sense to say you want to assign 2 instances of the same crew, say Crew A, to a particular job plan.  If, for example, two instances of the same type of team are required to perform the work you probably need to define two distinctly separate crews of the same crew type and add each crew (not Crew Type) to the Job Plan rather than customise the system to allow you to add a crew type with a quantity greater than 1.

Alternatively you could assign crafts to the job plan which you then have the option of specifying that the job plan requires, say 5 electricians, for example for 6 hours.

From Administration -> Organisations you can select an Organisation then click Crew Assignment Options to define how total work hours are calculated for Work Orders, Job Plans, Tasks and Activities associated with Crews.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for explaining this a bit more in detail